# Avoiding starvation with a C++ notify_all()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, design-patterns

My barrier synchronisation scenario is this:

a. Threads take a step forward in synchronisation - i.e. they complete one unit of task and then wait for all the other threads to do the same, then when they do, they can move forward again.

b. I have a large number of threads (around 256) waiting on a condition variable. When the condition is met a `notify_all()` will be sent.

c. (Part where starvation risk arises): Immediately before the `notify_all()` is called, a `runnable` variable is set to `true` and a counter - `completed` - is set to zero. When a thread completes its task unit, it calls a function which first sets `runnable` to `false`, then increments the `completed` variable - the condition is met when `completed` equals the threshold (namely the number of threads that need to complete a task unit), where upon `runnable` is set to true.

I.e., we wait like this:

```
cond.wait(lck, runnable == true);
```

And have this:

```
unique_lock<mutex> lck(runMut);
runnable = true;
cond.notify_all();
```

My concern is that any woken thread could complete its task and then call into the `wait()` function before a thread further down the chain has been woken. When this "lower" thread tests `runnable`, it will find it set to `false` and so go back to sleep.

Is there a design pattern or some other way I can get round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not actually find a way to get this to work - the problem is that the two variables solution suggested above does not deal with spurious wake ups and so I opted to simplify this by not bothering with the predicate at all and living with the problem of the spurious wake ups.

Answer (score 2):

You could use two condition variables. One to notify the workers to start working and one to signal back that a worker has finished. I.e. your main thread would look like this:

```
for (;;) {
  running = 0;
  done = 0;
  cond_run.notify_all();
  cond_done.wait(lck, []() { return done == threads; });
  // handle results
}
```

And your worker thread would look like this:

```
for (;;) {
  cond_run.wait(lck, []() { return running < threads; });
  ++running;
  lck.unlock();
  // do work
  lck.lock():
  ++done;
  cond_done.notify_one();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Concurrency is hard.  There are lots of ways to solve this problem, but the really important thing is to make it easy for yourself to be absolutely sure that it does the right thing.  In this particular case, using a boolean "runnable" to indicate when threads can start running is confusing.

Instead, I would use an int currentStage to indicate which stage everyone is supposed to be executing, and an int numComplete to indicate how many threads have finished currentStage.  make sure that the state is only accessed under lock and only undergoes valid transitions -- the thread that increments numComplete to 256 should also reset it to 0 and increment currentStage before releasing the lock.

Make sure that notify_all is fired after any change to that state, and then it will be easy to make sure that each thread is doing the right thing.